# Return Value from Stored Procedure not set

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, return-value

I have the following very basic stored procedure:

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNumberToProcess]

AS

RETURN 999

I then have some code using Enterprise Library to run and get the return value:

```
        Dim cmd As DbCommand
        Dim ResultValue as String
        Dim lDBCommand as String = "dbo.GetNumberToProcess"
        Dim actionDB As Sql.SqlDatabase = New Sql.SqlDatabase(lConnectionString)
        cmd = actionDB.GetSqlStringCommand(lDBCommand)

        Dim SQLreturnValue As New SqlParameter("RETURN_VALUE", DbType.Int32)
        SQLreturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

        cmd.Parameters.Add(SQLreturnValue)

        ' Execute the command and put the result into the ResultValue for later processing
        actionDB.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd).ToString()
        ResultValue = cmd.Parameters("RETURN_VALUE").Value.ToString
```

Problem is that all I ever get back as ResultValue is "0" when I should get "999" (the Stored Proc is very cut down just so that I can get to the bottom of why it's not working).

According to the multiple examples I've seen on the web this should work.

Anyone got any suggestions as to why it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored proc is obviously fine, I don't use the EntLib much I think your problem is the line

```
cmd = actionDB.GetSqlStringCommand(lDBCommand)
```

Try using this instead

```
cmd = actionDB.GetStoredProcCommand(lDBCommand)
```

Comment: This works, do you know why? I suspect with the GetSQLStringCommand it is not passing through the Return Value.

Answer (score 1):

have your tried

```
ResultValue = SQLreturnValue.Value.ToString()
```

I think that's just a syntax thing tho, shouldn't make a diff.

I personally do not have a name for my return param and it works fine:

```
var returnCode = new SqlParameter();
returnCode.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
returnCode.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
```

Maybe the name RETURN_VALUE is messing with it?

Comment: Yes, had that originally and changed it to what it is now in case it made a difference. Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Change your procedure to be REALLY simple:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNumberToProcess] AS RETURN 999
```

Is ResultValue still 0 after this change?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to get back an output parameter instead of a resultset you need to declare an output parameter in your sproc and assign it a value.

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNumberToProcess]
(
    @rtInt as int OUT
)
AS

select  @rtInt  = 999

---

Dim SQLreturnValue As New SqlParameter("@rtInt", DbType.Int32)

ResultValue = cmd.Parameters("@rtInt").Value.ToString

Comment: Actually you don't need to set an output parameter. ReturnValue is a kind of inbuilt output parameter that you get from a stored procedure without having to first declare it. Only limitation is that it can only be an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your code isn't handling the result very well. Short answer: try changing your stored procedure to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNumberToProcess]

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
RETURN 999

GO
```

The NOCOUNT setting will prvent SQL from sending the '1 record(s) affected' which could influence your return value.

Comment: This had an answer accepted last year, the problem was he was calling the sproc as a SQL statement, hence the background code wasn't picking up the return value.